# $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are integrable $\Rightarrow$ $g+f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I think the statement is true because if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable, $\overline{I}_a^b(f)=\underline{I}_a^b(f)$ and$\overline{I}_a^b(g)=\underline{I}_a^b(g)$ by theorem. That means for $f$, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, such that

$U_f(P)-L_f(P)\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and same thing for $g$. Combining, we get

$U_f(P)-L_f(P)+U_g(P)-L_f(P)\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow$ $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, such that

$U_{f+g}(P)-L_{f+g}(P)\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow f+g$ is integrable. But I think

the proof is rather rough, so could anyone point out the mistakes?

Comment: $U_{f+g}(P) = U_f(P) + U_g(P)$, etc.  is not necessarily true unless both functions are increasing or decreasing together. But you can say $U_{f+g}(P) \leqslant  U_f(P) + U_g(P)$ and $L_{f+g}(P) \geqslant  L_f(P) + L_g(P)$ which will help you finish.

Answer (score 1):

There are some gaps, if not mistakes: First of all, you might find $P_1, P_2$ so that

$$U_f(P_1) - L_f(P_1) <\epsilon, \ \ \ U_g(P_2) - L_g(P_2)<\epsilon.$$

You need to find the common refinement $P = P_1 \cup P_2$ so that the above holds with $P$ replacing $P_i$, as suggested in the question.

Also, from

$$U_f(P_1) - L_f(P_1) + U_g(P_2) - L_g(P_2) <\epsilon$$
to 
$$U_{f+g}(P) - L_{f+g}(P) <\epsilon,$$
you might want more justifications. You are essentially using that on each subintervals $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$,

$$m_i(f) + m_i(g) \le f(x) + g(x) \le M_i (f) + M_i(g).$$